# UDP bind failure

Tags: java, networking, udp

I'm trying to connect to a remote server, but i get a `BindException` when i instanciate the `DatagramSocket` with a remote server address.  It works on localhost.

```
dstAddress = new InetSocketAddress(server, servPort);
srcAddress = new InetSocketAddress(srcPort);

try{
sock = new DatagramSocket();
sock.setReuseAddress(true);
} catch (SocketException ex) {

}

public void connect() {
sock.bind(srcAddress);
sock.connect(dstAddress);
}
```

Comment: You might be trying to bind the socket to a remote (or otherwise invalid) address. Hard to tell without any code.

Comment: I tried several piece of code so it is hard to show you what i did exactly, the remote address is correct as i can connect with TCP.

Comment: Put together minimal compilable code that exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call `bind()` at all. A port was already chosen for you when the DatagramSocket was created. `connect()` is also not required, you can choose to set the destination address in each DatagramPacket instead.

Answer (score 0):

The source port is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

Use 0 for your `scrPort`. This will allow the OS to choose an open port when you bind the socket.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `bind()` or `connect()`. The source port is chosen in the [DatagramSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) constructor (as you have already done) and the destination address and port are set in each [DatagramPacket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) you send.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice:
- Never specify a source port if there is no need to do so.